# Powershell - get console output into variable (not stdout, not stderror)

Tags: powershell, redirect, output, exe, stderr

I have the exe from Lenovo that only provides command line output when run from a cmd window but not from PowerShell.  The output seems to come from a ghost source other than StdOut or StdErr.
https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n2hgc06w.exe   (you have to run and click install but all that does is unzip to c:\drivers\win\touchpadfw).  Be sure to cancel the install prompt after extract.

This command gives me output to the console

```
& cmd.exe /c c:\drivers\win\touchpadfw\touchpadfw_aug2019\synreflash.exe /v /S 2
```

This also gives me output the the console and nothing in the variable

```
$var = (& cmd.exe /c c:\drivers\win\touchpadfw\touchpadfw_aug2019\synreflash.exe /v /S 2) 2>&1
```

Same here

```
$var = (& cmd.exe /c c:\drivers\win\touchpadfw\touchpadfw_aug2019\synreflash.exe /v /S 2 2>&1)
```

I feel like this exe is outputting in some other way than StdOut and StdErr but I don't know what.  Nothing I've tried can capture what it is outputting.  Is there a third method of output?

This is where it gets weird.  Using "start cmd" to open a cmd window from the admin PowerShell, I run the exe directly in the cmd window but the output goes to the parent powershell console.  I cannot get any output if I start the cmd window as admin directly.

Comment: Have you tried [redirecting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1) all output with `*>&1`?

Comment: @Iconiu, let me know if the updated solution below answers your questions, if yes, you can click the green tickbox to mark as resolved. Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the ***SynReflash*** usage below you will notice that you would need to pass the last arg as *`/S 3`* explicitly, to *print* to *`Standard Output`* as opposed to  *`/S 2`* is a silent mode

---

[image]

```
$cmdOutput = cmd.exe /c "C:\DRIVERS\WIN\TouchpadFW\n2hgc06w\synreflash.exe" /v /S 3 '2>&1'
```

**OR**

```
proc = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start([System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]@
{
    'FileName'               = "cmd.exe"
    'Arguments'              = "/C " + """C:\DRIVERS\WIN\TouchpadFW\n2hgc06w\synreflash.exe"" /v /s 3"
    'CreateNoWindow'         = $true
    'UseShellExecute'        = $false
    'RedirectStandardOutput' = $true   # to get stdout to $proc.StandardOutput
    'RedirectStandardError'  = $true   # to get stderr to $proc.StandardError
})
$output = $proc.StandardOutput
$error1 = $proc.StandardError
write-host $output.ReadToEnd()
```

**Output**

***FW Version: 1.2***

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but they do not work with this executable.  The first example looks like you are redirecting to a file then trying to read it's content.  The sample variable of $stdderror= "Error" is confusing as start-process wants a file name.  Giving it one results in empty files. It does output to the console of the parent powershell window, the one used to start powershell_ISE.    In the second example, both standardoutput and standarderror remain empty.  I changed the /s 2 to /s 1 to make sure the exe was running and will output in it's own window.

Comment: In my first example variable thats storing Get-Content was incorrect, I edited my answer

Comment: @Iconiu Can you please confirm if the updated solution answered your questions, if yes, you [can mark as resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)